# Conversion (const char*) var goes wrong

Tags: c++, mfc, char, double, c-strings

I need to convert from CString to double in Embedded Visual C++, which supports only old style C++. I am using the following code

`CString str = "4.5";
double var = atof( (const char*) (LPCTSTR) str )`

and resutlt is `var=4.0`, so I am loosing decimal digits.
I have made another test

`LPCTSTR str = "4.5";
const char* var = (const char*) str`

and result again `var=4.0`
Can anyone help me to get a correct result?

Comment: Are you sure that the source (`str`) really points to the string you think it does? If you step through the code in a debugger, what does it tell you?

Comment: It could be a localization issue. Have a look at [`setlocale()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale). In certain languages (e.g. German) the meaning of `.` and `,` are swapped. If a German locale is active, the parsing of `"4.0"` stopps at `.`. (In this case, `"4,5"` would return the correct result `4.5`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using scanf

`CString str="4.5"
 double var=0.0;
 _stscanf( str, _T("%lf"), &var );`

This gives a correct result `var=4.5`
Thanks everyone for comments and help.

Answer (score 1):

`CString` is not `const char*` To convert a TCHAR CString to ASCII, use the CT2A macro - this will also allow you to convert the string to UTF8 (or any other Windows code page):

```
// Convert using the local code page
CString str(_T("Hello, world!"));
CT2A ascii(str);
TRACE(_T("ASCII: %S\n"), ascii.m_psz);

// Convert to UTF8
CString str(_T("Some Unicode goodness"));
CT2A ascii(str, CP_UTF8);
TRACE(_T("UTF8: %S\n"), ascii.m_psz);
```

Comment: There macros are part of ATL, not C++ standard. Read this for instruction of usage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/87zae4a3(v=vs.140). Most likely you are not including the headrs. 
#include <atldef.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

Comment: No, _wtof is not present, only atof

Comment: I did not try to include atldef.h, since I found a solution by using scanf (see the unswer below). But thank you very much for help.

Comment: The final paragraph is wrong. The issue here is about character **encoding**, not the particular characters being used. The string `"4.5"` is encoded as `34 2E 35 00 ` (ASCII) and `34 00 2E 00 35 00 00 00` (UTF-16 LE). When you cast the Unicode string to an ASCII (or ANSI) string, you are truncating it, resulting in the string `34 00`. That latter piece of code only works, when your project is set to use MBCS encoding, something you do not ever want.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is, that you are lying to the compiler, and the compiler trusts you. Using Embedded Visual C++ I'm going to assume, that you are targeting Windows CE. Windows CE exposes a Unicode API surface only, so your project is very likely set to use Unicode (UTF-16 LE encoding).

In that case, `CString` expands to `CStringW`, which stores code units as `wchar_t`. When doing `(const char*) (LPCTSTR) str` you are then casting from a `wchar_t const*` to a `char const*`. Given the input, the first byte has the value 52 (the ASCII encoding for the character `4`). The second byte has the value 0. That is interpreted as the terminator of the C-style string. In other words, you are passing the string `"4"` to your call to `atof`. Naturally, you'll get the value `4.0` as the result.

To fix the code, use something like the following:

```
CStringW str = L"4.5";
double var = _wtof( str.GetString() );
```

[_wtof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/atof-atof-l-wtof-wtof-l) is a Microsoft-specific extension to its CRT.

Note two things in particular:

- The code uses a `CString` variant with *explicit* character encoding (`CStringW`). Always be explicit about your string types. This helps read your code and catch bugs before they happen (although all those C-style casts in the original code defeats that entirely).
- The code calls the [CString::GetString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring) member to retrieve a pointer to the immutable buffer. This, too, makes the code easier to read, by not using what looks to be a C-style cast (but is an operator instead).

Also consider defining the [_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#remarks-8) macro to prevent inadvertent character set conversions from happening (e.g. `CString str = "4.5";`). This, too, helps you catch bugs early (unless you defeat that with C-style casts as well).

Comment: Unfotunatly, there is no wchar_t type in Embedded Visual C++ 4.0, as well as there is no method GetString in that version of MFC for CString. Besides that you only critisizing without giving an answer to the question. So you comment is not relevant.

Comment: Use `WCHAR` in case the compiler doesn't support `wchar_t`. If your version of MFC doesn't provide the `GetString` member, use `operator LPCWSTR()`.